# Как вставить скрипт из кода js?

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой js-код:

```
var advert = '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>...код рекламы...<script>...<script>';
$(advert).insertAfter('.block');
```

но ничего не происходит. Ошибка из-за того, что в тексте имеется закрывающий тег script, как я понял, поэтому скрипт не срабатывает.
Подскажите, как правильно вставить такой код?

Comment: `'</scr'+'ipt>'`

Comment: благодарю, не знал это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите закрывающий тег и экранируйте /

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var advert = "<script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'><\/script>console.log(111)<script>console.log(222)<\/script>";
$(advert).insertAfter('.block');
})
```

```html
<div class="block">aaaa</div>
```

Comment: у тега скрипт по спецификации обязан быть закрывающий тег

Comment: ну смотрите, если указан SRC, то тег должен быть "самозакрывающимся". А вот если вы хотите в HTML внести исполняемый JS код, тогда да, он пишется  <script> YOUR CODE </script>.

Comment: нет, `</script>` должен быть в любом случае

Comment: У меня работает и так и так, но всё же поправил, проштудирую вопрос, спасибо за поправку